# Координаты Layout после поворота

Tags: android, android-layout, view

Поворачиваю Layout с помощью метода setRotate(), после поворота координаты полученные с помощью getX, getY не меняются.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как я могу после поворота получить реальные координаты точки А1, а лучше всех четырех углов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте волшебный мир математики. Получите координаты до поворота с помощью `getX`, `getY`, затем трансформируйте их с помощью поворачивающей матрицы на такой же угол, на какой повернули вьюху.

Вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24583341/3100967) пример как это делатся доступными на Android классами.

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.postRotate(angleInDegrees);
float point[] = { xValue, yValue };
matrix.mapPoints(point); 
// Здесь в point будут уже новые координаты
```